# Google Cloud Big Query Scheduled Queries weird error relating JURISDICTION

Tags: google-bigquery

All my datasheets, tables, and ALL items inside BQ are un EU. When I try to do a View->to->Table 15 min scheduled query I get an error regarding my location, which is incorrect, because all, source and destiny are both on EU...

Anyone knows why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a transient known issue matching your situation, GCP support team needs more time for troubleshooting. There may be a potential issue in the UI. I would ask you to try the following steps:

- Firstly, try to make the same operation in Chrome's incognito mode.
- Another possible workaround is trying to follow this [official guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_scheduled_query) using a different approach than the UI (CLI for instance).

I hope it helps.